Confusion in the greatest common divisor and coprimality of fractional ideals
I'm now reading Chapter VII of the english translation of Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory". At the beginning of Section 6 of Chapter VII, it is said that

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be an integral ideal of the number field $K$, and let $J^{\mathfrak{m}}$ be the group of all ideals of K which are relatively prime to $\mathfrak{m}$.

I couldn't find the definition for a fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ being relatively prime to $\mathfrak{m}$. By consulting the subsequent text or some other sources, I found that it means that the prime factorization of $\mathfrak{a}$ contains none of prime ideals of $\mathfrak{m}$ even to the negative power. Namely,

Definition 1. Two fractional ideals $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{m}$ of $K$ are relatively prime if $v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\mathfrak{a})=0$ for any prime factor of $\mathfrak{m}$.

On the other hand, on p. 486, the notion of the greatest common divisor is extended to ideal numbers, which is made possible with the aid of the greatest common divisors of fractional ideals. Again, I am not sure what is the greatest common divisor of fractional ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$. In order to make the greatest common divisor compatible with the divisibility of fractional ideals (defined in terms of the set inclusion), we need to use the definition

Definition 2. For two fractional ideals $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ of $K$,
we define their greatest common divisor $(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b})$ by
$$
(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}) := \mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}.
$$

Definition 2 is compatible with the definition via prime factorization
$$
(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}) = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}}\mathfrak{p}^{\min(v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\mathfrak{a}),v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\mathfrak{a}))}.
$$
However, the above definitions makes the usual relation
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\label{confusing}
(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b})=\mathscr{O}
\iff
\text{$\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are relatively prime}
\end{equation}
false for fractional ideals $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$.
Indeed, if $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=\mathscr{O}$, then both of $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ should be integral.
This seems quite uncomfortable for me and I suspect one of the above definitions (I suspect that Definition 1 is) unconventional. Therefore, the questions are

Q1. Which one of the above definitions unconventional?


Q2. How one can understand the above confusing situation \eqref{confusing} more cleanly?

